# Do Large (and larger) creatures drop equipment suitable for their size?

Tags: equipment, creature-size, pathfinder-2e

I noticed there isn't an indication of size on the equipment of Large (and larger) creatures. I'd assume they would drop weapons and armor corresponding with their own size, but the illustrations of some creatures depict them one-handing two-handed weapons, such as the Stone Giant wielding a greatclub:

[image: Stone Giant]

Is there a hard-and-fast rule on the size of equipment dropped by Large or larger creatures?

Comment: Not sure why, but as I read the question title I envisioned a party fighting against a Mammoth, and afterwards all they find is the thong that it was wearing.

Comment: Huh, I thought of weapons but hadn't looked at the Bestiary enough to notice that some seem to have undersized weapons. This bears investigation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No.

Monster and NPC creation does not follow the rules for Player Character creation found in the CRB. Instead they use the guidelines found in the Gamemastery Guide.

> Creatures aren’t built the same way PCs are. The rules for building them are more flexible, and their statistics are based on benchmark final numbers rather than combining each individual modifier together. This is called top-down design, in which you consider the design process as a whole and select the details that reflect your intended result, rather than building statistics from the bottom up and hoping the finished creature matches your vision.

-- From the [Gamesmastery Guide, on building creatures](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=995)

Monster design, including loot, is top down. That is to say, you start with the end goal in mind, of which narrative sense is usually a part, and choose numbers and loot that fit what you, or the designer wants to accomplish.

Consulting the [gamemaster's guide on monster creation, under items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1008) size is not considered specifically. Instead, the focus of that section is entirely on player wealth.
If for thematic reasons the monster wields a weapon that is unusable for the players, it's potential impact on player wealth should still be considered - for them, it may as well be [objet d'art](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1110). In fact this might be a creative and thematic way of providing your characters with money!

However, [the section on monster damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1018) does consider monsters wielding manufactured weapons in the sidebar, but again primarily from a top down perspective; what are the your/the designers goals, for this monster, and this encounter?

In general, the monster's overall damage is balanced for the encounter, rather than the specific weapon. If the monster is themed as wielding a tiny dagger, then it has abilities that compensate for the dagger's low damage.

The final paragraph of the sidebar may be particularly relevant for some GMs considering this question, and wanting to give a Giant Instinct Barbarian a cool weapon;

> On the flip side, you might want to use a one-off creature as a source of a particularly high-level piece of treasure, such as a magic weapon. In these cases, you might want to make the attack bonus higher for the potency rune or the damage higher for a potent striking rune so the PCs feel the weapon’s effect before they obtain it. This will make the treasure feel more powerful, since they’ve already been on the receiving end.

N.b. As a GM, I generally require armour to be adjusted to fit players before they can comfortably use it, via a relatively simple crafting check and time, even when taken from a humanoid of the same size category. I'd probably allow something similar - with a more substantial crafting check if they decided they wanted a giant's armour.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: According to the section on Items of Different Sizes: "Creatures of sizes other than Small or Medium need items appropriate to their size."

Comment: @YopiLapi Those rules are for players and player characters. I am talking about monster design, which in PF2 uses different rules.

Comment: Those are the rules of the game, they talk about creatures, it doesn't matter if they're PCs or NPCs, as far as I know nowhere in the Bestiary says that the rules from the CRB don't apply to NPCs.

Comment: There are multiple lines in the GM's guide that say so, for example: 'If you gave a creature gear equivalent to a PC, your PCs would gain a huge amount of treasure by defeating a large group of them.' -- from the GMG's chapter on items.

Comment: 'Creatures aren’t built the same way PCs are. The rules for building them are more flexible, and their statistics are based on benchmark final numbers rather than combining each individual modifier together. This is called top-down design, in which you consider the design process as a whole and select the details that reflect your intended result, rather than building statistics from the bottom up and hoping the finished creature matches your vision.' from the GMG opening statements on building creatures.

Comment: I've added an opening paragraph, that should help clarify this.

Comment: None of those quotes say anything about NPCs not needing to follow the basic rules of the game. Sure, NPCs don't have as much wealth as a PC of their level, and they are built differently. But they still have to follow the rules of the game: they get 3 actions per turn, they can flank opponents, they have a bulk limit, etc. One of those rules is that creatures of sizes other than Small or Medium need items appropriate to their size.

Comment: The text you are quoting comes from the CRB's chapter 6. The opening lines of which are 'Your character starts out with 15 gold pieces (150 silver pieces) to spend on any common items from this chapter. Items with an uncommon rarity can be purchased only if you have special access from abilities you selected during character creation or your GM gives you permission to purchase them.

Once you’ve purchased your starting items, there are three main ways to gain new items and equipment: you can find them during an adventure, make them using the Crafting skill, or purchase them from a merchant.'

Comment: This entire chapter is about Player Character (PC) creation.

Comment: Possibly you will find the quote I actually added to my answer more satisfactory: 'Creatures aren’t built the same way PCs are. The rules for building them are more flexible' - Gamesmastery Guide, Building Creatures